# Searching capability on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a page in my web app whereby users can enter in either a code or the customer name. from there if they enter the code it pulls all the data from tables with that ID code. If they enter a name it pulls all the entries of that name and the associated ID (obviously they dont know the ID. The following is my form helper which brings up a new html page. I'm stuck on the controller information to go with it.

```
<%= form_tag("searchshow", method: "get") do %>   
<%= label_tag(:q, "Company Name:", :class=>'s') %>
<%= text_field_tag(:q) %>
<%= submit_tag("Search") %><br><br>
<%= label_tag(:q, "ID No:", :class=>'s') %>
<%= text_field_tag(:q) %>
<%= submit_tag("Search") %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would set 2 different names for the text fields:

```
<%= form_tag("searchshow", method: "get") do %>   
  <%= label_tag(:name, "Company Name:", :class=>'s') %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:name) %>
  <%= submit_tag("Search") %>
  <br><br>
  <%= label_tag(:id, "ID No:", :class=>'s') %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:id) %>
  <%= submit_tag("Search") %>
<% end %>
```

And in the controller, check which of the text field has been used by the user. Example:

```
def get 
  if params[:id].present?
    # you get the user with: User.find(params[:id])
    # throws an error if the user is not found
  elsif  
    # you get the list of possible users with: User.where(code: params[:name]) 
    # returns an empty list if no user matches the name
  end
end
```

The code may look a bit different if you're using Rails 4 and StrongParameters